# "Insufficient free space" when trying to increase swap space on LVM?

Tags: swap, lvm

I installed Ubuntu 21.10 with LVM to use full encryption on my disk. It works great, the only problem is that it chose a 1gb swap partition size, while I have 16gb or ram...

```
me@me:~$ sudo vgs
  VG       #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize    VFree
  vgubuntu   1   2   0 wz--n- <475,71g    0 

me@me:~$ sudo lvdisplay
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/vgubuntu/root
  LV Name                root
  VG Name                vgubuntu
  LV UUID                ky0PoX-T89V-D2IG-zmfk-gofT-dD0o-A4gC4g
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time ubuntu, 2021-11-07 22:06:47 +0100
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                474,75 GiB
  Current LE             121536
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:1
   
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/vgubuntu/swap_1
  LV Name                swap_1
  VG Name                vgubuntu
  LV UUID                cLXRIh-3Tjp-fzUn-mKwe-akK0-4hPr-9I7l3c
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time ubuntu, 2021-11-07 22:06:47 +0100
  LV Status              available
  # open                 2
  LV Size                980,00 MiB
  Current LE             245
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:2
```

But when I try to extend I get this

```
me@me:~$ sudo lvextend -L+16GB /dev/vgubuntu/swap_1
  Insufficient free space: 4096 extents needed, but only 0 available
```

What is the safest way to increase the swap?

Comment: What are you extending into? Logical volumes can only be extended into available space 

Comment: You have already used used all available space - root is 474.75 GB, so you will have to reduce root lv with 16GB before expanding swap with the same amount.

Comment: @SorenA yes that makes sense, I can gladly reduce the root, I have more than 100gb free there, how would I do that? I never used LVM

Comment: @Lele83x it should be something like `sudo lvreduce --resizefs -L -16GB /dev/vgubuntu/root`  to reduce root by 16  GB. I don't have a LVM system to verify it on, but according to the manual it is right. Remember that you also have to run 'mkswap' on the expanded swap lv.

Comment: @SorenA thanks I will test it out, need to spin a liveusb first

Comment: @Lele83x I think that you should be able to work on LVM with system running an filesystems mounted.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, why don't you use a swapfile? https://askubuntu.com/questions/839033/what-is-swapfile-and-swapspace

Comment: @SadaharuWakisaka won't it interfere with the swap partition as a separate LV?

Comment: @SorenA it sounds very risky... are you sure it's a good idea to resize the root while mounted and in use?

Comment: @Lele83x As long as you don't reduce below available space it should be ok ... but it is up to you.  But always have a fresh backup !!

Comment: @Lele83x, no it doesn't. swap partition and file can both work at the same time. Swap file/partition could be in anywhere.